# Can't see newly added item in checkedlist box

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I am working on a c# program where there is a CheckedListbox `host_listbox`.

In my code I have a option for adding new items to the `checkedlistbox`. When am done adding the new item I can't see the newly added item in my `checkedlistbox` till the program is closed and run again.

I have tried

```
Refresh()
BeginUpdate()
EndUpdate()
```

but they are not working.

When adding new item is done, it is showing the newly added item in the `ITEMS` of `checkedlistbox`, it is not being displayed though.

Can anyone suggest me some alternative way to make it work?

```
public static void fill_checkboxlist()
{
    host_listbox.Items.Clear();
    host_listbox.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, host_config> hlitem in host_list)
    {
        string sitem = hlitem.Key;
        if (host_list[sitem].sessionOptions == null)
            host_list[sitem].sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
        host_list[sitem].sessionOptions.Protocol = Protocol.Sftp;
        host_list[sitem].sessionOptions.HostName = host_list[sitem].ip;
        host_list[sitem].sessionOptions.UserName = host_list[sitem].username;
        host_list[sitem].sessionOptions.Password = host_list[sitem].password;
        host_list[sitem].sessionOptions.PortNumber = Convert.ToInt32(host_list[sitem].port);
        //host_list[sitem].sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = host_list[sitem].rsa;
        host_listbox.Items.Add(hlitem.Key.ToString(), false);
    }  

    host_listbox.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: show the code you used to add item

Comment: do you use binding for that list?

Comment: okkk. i have to explain you a bit before adding the code.
i am maintaining a config.ini from where am reading the contents into a dictionary and loading the key of each entry into the checkedlistbox. when adding the new item am using the reverse procedure. i.e stroing the new item in the dictionary-->> writing it  into the config.ini then reading the contents of the config file to reload the items in the checkedlistbox

Comment: no i have not used any bindings.

Comment: what code you have been used to add item in listbox?

Comment: host_list is the Dict. host_listbox is the CheckedListBox

Comment: this function just Adds item to host_listbox from host_list.

Comment: @NiravKamani  the problem lies just in displaying the new item in the CheckedListBox.it has been added already in the CheckedListBox

Comment: @NiravKamani checkedListBox has no method showAllItems()

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add this command at the end of your method:

```
host_listbox.EndUpdate();
```

When you call fill_checkboxlist() form XXXX_Load method, it will not work when you omit this line. I also do not think you absolutely need to call the Refresh method...

If you still have problems, try to check this:

In your XXXXX.Designer.cs file look at #region Windows Form Designer generated code. There you will  see generated code and there may be something you do not see and is causing your problems. There should be something like this:

```
        //
        // host_listbox
        // 
        this.host_listbox.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.host_listbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 36);
        this.host_listbox.Name = "host_listbox";
        this.host_listbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(179, 169);
        this.host_listbox.TabIndex = 0;
```

### EDIT:

Your method should not be static!
Try to modify your method like this and see what happens.

```
  public void fill_checkboxlist()
  {
        host_listbox.Items.Clear();
        host_listbox.BeginUpdate();
        host_listbox.Items.Add("A", false);
        host_listbox.Items.Add("B", false);
        host_listbox.Items.Add("C", false);
        host_listbox.EndUpdate();
  }
```

If you think it needs to be static, you must do it like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fill_checkboxlist(host_listbox);
    }

    public static void fill_checkboxlist(CheckedListBox chlb)
    {
        chlb.Items.Clear();
        chlb.BeginUpdate();
        chlb.Items.Add("A", false);
        chlb.Items.Add("B", false);
        chlb.Items.Add("C", false);
        chlb.EndUpdate();
    }
```

Also I do not understand, why is your method marked as public....

Comment: yes EndUpdate is there but it was omitted while posting. sorry for that

Comment: everything in Designer.cs is as same as you have written.

Comment: yes from load event handler and also from Add_item_bttn_click Event

Comment: my add_item event is in another form. if the method isnt static how will i access it from the other form?

Comment: Didn't get u. this method fill_checkboxlist() is written in Form1. Form2 is accessing this method that is why i made the method as public static

Comment: The New Item is being added in the checklistbox.  But something is missing that is not letting the control to redraw or refresh or display the newly added item